# Парсинг JSON в Oracle 11g

Tags: json, plsql, oracle11g

Нужно распарсить строку Json, включающей структуры и массивы структур. Понимаю, что вопрос поднимался, но пол часа гуглинга не дали удовлетворительного результата в силу имеющихся ограничений:

- Мы не можем устанавливать крупные фреймворки (кроме компиляции одного
  отдельного пакета). Это лишает нас [APEX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/downloads/index.html).
- Мы не можем использовать временные таблицы. Это лишает нас [этого](https://habr.com/ru/post/195496/) парсера.

Но есть обычные для plsql возможности:

- Любые коллекции
- Типы данных, объявленные на уровне пакета.
- Собственно, в рамках одного пакета любой код, не противоречащий ограничениям.

Итак. Как пример рассмотрим:

```
vSrc :=
'{
  "NAME": "Петров Александр",
  "AGE": "35",
  "PARTNER":{
    "NAME":"Петрова Дарья",
    "AGE":"33"
  }
  "CHILDREN": [
    {
      "NAME": "Вася",
      "AGE": "4"
    },
    {
      "NAME": "Маша",
      "AGE": "8"
    }
  ]
}'
```

Мы хотим иметь возможность по адресу получать или значение, или массив json-строк. Например:

```
v_result := jsonAPI.getJson(source => vSrc, address => 'PARTNER.NAME');
```

Возвращает значение 'Петрова Дарья', а вызов

```
v_result := jsonAPI.getJson(source => vSrc, address => 'CHILDREN');
```

Вернет коллекцию, выведя которую кодом:

```
dbms_output.put_line('Первый ребенок:');
dbms_output.put_line(v_result(1));
dbms_output.put_line('Второй ребенок:');
dbms_output.put_line(v_result(2));
```

Мы увидим

```
Первый ребенок:
{"NAME":"Вася","AGE":"4"}
Второй ребенок:
{"NAME":"Маша","AGE":"8"}
```

Таким образом, мы можем использовать элементы этой коллекции как параметр для вызова того же api.

Есть ли способ парсить JSON примерно в таком духе на чистом PLSQL? Какие-то известные библиотеки с открытым кодом, например, или вроде того?

Comment: Если ничего, что существует, неустраивает, то почему не написать свой парсер. _Это лишает нас этого парсера_, а почему там не заменить временную таблицу на коллекцию? Тогда уже не надо всё с нуля писать.

Comment: @0xdb именно этим сейчас и занят, да=). Причина как часто бывает - в сроках. Велосипедостроение может первратить один вечер на таск в пару дней. Мне кажется, задача то должна быть супер-распространена. Но я так и не нашел подходящего варианта. APEX, PL/JSON и этот парсер. Пришлось брать его и переделывать. Тем более, там нет инструментов для запросов к получившейся структуре. Но в целом, я уже близок к чему-то юзабельному.